# rabbitmq dashboard is not accessible from kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rabbitmq

kubernetes cluster is running on two nodes. one master , one worker ... 
weave net is pod network.

```
[root@irf-centos1 ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.8.156.184:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.8.156.184:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

have deployed the rabbit docker image as container in kubernetes pod.

```
[root@irf-centos1 ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
rabbitmq-86bd97fd9d-8h444   1/1     Running   0          51m
rabbitmq-86bd97fd9d-n2kgk   1/1     Running   0          51m
```

following are the service and deployment yaml file

**deployment file**

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmqapp
    spec:
      containers:
        -
          image: "docker.io/rabbitmq:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: rabbitmq
          ports:
            -
              containerPort: 5672
              name: http-port
          volumeMounts:
            -
              mountPath: /var/rabbitmqapp_home
              name: rabbitmqapp-home
      volumes:
        -
          emptyDir: {}
          name: rabbitmqapp-home
```

**service file**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    -
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31111
  selector:
    app: rabbitmqapp
  type: NodePort
```

here are the services and deployment details

```
[root@irf-centos1 ~]# kubectl get deployments
NAME       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
rabbitmq   2/2     2            2           55m


[root@irf-centos1 ~]# kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          3d
rabbitmq     NodePort    10.98.204.64   <none>        5672:31111/TCP   55m
```

now, when i am trying to hit the rabbitmq dashboard/UI on the node port. it is not accessible

```
[root@irf-centos1 ~]# curl http://10.8.156.187:31111
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
AMQP    [root@irf-centos1 ~]#
```

when i hit the same URL from the web browser, nothing is happening

please suggest

NOTE: this cluster is deployed using kubeadm on AZure VMs. for troubleshooting purpose, i have opened all inbound/outbound ports on these VMs so that , it should not be a firewall , port blocking issue.

**Edit 1:**

I modified the service file as follows and redeployed the same. PSB

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: ui
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
      nodePort: 31112
    - name: service
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31111
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  type: NodePort
```

still getting the same error

```
[root@irf-centos1 ~]# curl -I http://guest:guest@10.8.156.187:31111/api/users
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
AMQP    [root@irf-centos1 ~]# curl -I http://guest:guest@10.8.156.187:31112/api/users
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.8.156.187:31112; Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, was using the wrong docker image ... for rabbitmq dashbaord, the docker image should be docker:management. i changed that and it worked.

here is the updated service and deployment yaml file :

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq
    spec:
      containers:
        -
          image: "docker.io/rabbitmq:management"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: rabbitmq
          ports:
            -
              containerPort: 15672
              name: http-port
          volumeMounts:
            -
              mountPath: /var/rabbitmqapp_home
              name: rabbitmqapp-home
      volumes:
        -
          emptyDir: {}
          name: rabbitmqapp-home
```

service yaml file :

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: ui
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
      nodePort: 31112
    - name: service
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31111
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
  type: NodePort
```

Answer (score 2):

For rabbitmq dashboard/UI, it's running on : `15672`

So port number in service file should be included : `15672`

Then access to dashboard/UI create user for application. then `curl` using this user.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    -
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31111
    - 
      protocol: TCP
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
      nodePort: 31112

  selector:
    app: rabbitmqapp
  type: NodePort
```

Or using default username & password `guest` of rabitmq:

```
curl -I http://guest:guest@10.8.156.187:31112/api/users
```

Deployment file add containerPort:

```
      image: "docker.io/rabbitmq:latest"
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      name: rabbitmq
      ports:
        -
          containerPort: 5672
          name: http-port
          containerPort: 15672
          name: ui-port
```

Comment: please suggest. i modified the service and deployments too and deployed again .. still the issue

Comment: how did you get after edit 1 was changed, for this command : `kubectl get services`